# Google drive API downloading file nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

Im trying to get the contents of a file using the google drive API v3 in node.js.
I read in this documentation I get a stream back from `drive.files.get({fileId, alt: 'media'})`but that isn't the case. I get a promise back.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Can someone tell me how I can get a stream from that method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the steam type from the method of `drive.files.get`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already done the authorization process for using Drive API.

For this, how about this answer? In this case, please use `responseType`. [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/bd0accce744ddd55abdd400efbe2bccd96dc6cdf/samples/drive/download.js#L45)

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the file is downloaded as the stream type and it is saved as a file.

#### Sample script:

```
var dest = fs.createWriteStream("###");  // Please set the filename of the saved file.
drive.files.get(
  {fileId: id, alt: "media"},
  {responseType: "stream"},
  (err, {data}) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    data
      .on("end", () => console.log("Done."))
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return process.exit();
      })
      .pipe(dest);
  }
);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the file is downloaded as the stream type and it is put to the buffer.

#### Sample script:

```
drive.files.get(
  {fileId: id, alt: "media",},
  {responseType: "stream"},
  (err, { data }) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    let buf = [];
    data.on("data", (e) => buf.push(e));
    data.on("end", () => {
      const buffer = Buffer.concat(buf);
      console.log(buffer);
    });
  }
);
```

### Reference:

- [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/)

Comment: thanks a lot, the responseType: 'stream' fixed the issue. But as you can see here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads the docs are clearly wrong. Are they planning to fix this?

Comment: @Laurent Dhont Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the modification points of the Document, I reported it. But I'm not sure when this modification is done. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not be relevant to the Author's question but it is relevant for anyone trying to download Gdrive images and who come to this question.

**If the images are public**, you don't have to use googleapis/google drive sdk to download the images.

The process to download images via the sdk is complex and requires authorization and app creation on Gcloud.

In the case if images are public, they can be download by using the below url:

```
const imageUrl = `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${imageId}`
```

And below code can be used to download the file, like any other file:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import request from 'request';

const download = (url, dest, cb) => {
    console.log(url);
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    const sendReq = request.get(url);
    
    // verify response code
    sendReq.on('response', (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return cb('Response status was ' + response.statusCode);
        }

        sendReq.pipe(file);
    });

    // close() is async, call cb after close completes
    file.on('finish', () => file.close(cb));

    // check for request errors
    sendReq.on('error', (err) => {
        fs.unlink(dest, () => cb(err.message)); // delete the (partial) file and then return the error
    });

    file.on('error', (err) => { // Handle errors
        fs.unlink(dest, () => cb(err.message)); // delete the (partial) file and then return the error
    });
};

download(imageUrl, 'ImageName');
```