# Google Drive API returning [Object]

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm currently trying to list all files that are an image in a google drive folder, and download them to ./images/{filename}.{extension}.

I got most up and running, but it's returning

```
files: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
```

Here is my code: (node v14, googleapis@39 (i think?))

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const config = require('./options.json')
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {
    client_secret,
    client_id,
    redirect_uris
  } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth
  });
  drive.files.list({
    folderId: config.folderID,
    q: "mimeType contains 'image' and trashed = false"
  }, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log("ERROR", error);
    }
    console.log(response);
    
    response.items.forEach(function(item) {
      var file = fs.createWriteStream("./" + item.title);
      file.on("finish", function() {
        console.log("downloaded", item.title);
      });

      // Download file
      drive.files.get({
        fileId: item.id,
        alt: "media"
      }).pipe(file);
    });
  });
}
```

This code is mostly copy-paste code, and I have to rewrite it, but I need a some-what working version to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your situation as follows.

- You want to download the image files from the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis@39.0.0 for Node.js.
- You have already been able to download a file from Google Drive using Drive API.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification points:

- I think that your script tries to use the properties for Drive API v2 with Drive API v3. For example, `items` and `title` for v2 are `files` and `name` for v3, respectively.

  - I thought that one of reasons of your issue might be this.
- About `drive.files.list({folderId: config.folderID, q: "mimeType contains 'image' and trashed = false"})`, unfortunately, `folderId` cannot be used. In this case, please include the folder ID in `q`.
- About the method for downloading the files, you can see the sample scripts at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62476413/7108653).

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({
    version: "v3",
    auth,
  });

  const folderId = "###"; // <--- Please set the folder ID.

  drive.files.list(
    {
      q: `mimeType contains 'image' and trashed = false and '${folderId}' in parents`,
    },
    function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        return console.log("ERROR", error);
      }
      console.log(response.data);
      const items = response.data.files;
      items.forEach(function (item) {
        drive.files
          .get({ fileId: item.id, alt: "media" }, { responseType: "stream" })
          .then((res) => {
            const dest = fs.createWriteStream("./" + item.name);
            res.data
              .on("end", () => {
                console.log("downloaded", item.name);
              })
              .on("error", (err) => {
                throw new Error(err);
              })
              .pipe(dest);
          });
      });
    }
  );
}
```

- When above script is used, when the image files are in the specific folder of `folderId`, the image files are downloaded.

#### Note:

- In above script, I could confirm that this could be worked for both googleapis@39.0.0 and googleapis@52.1.0 (the latest one).

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)